# Find span of control from an employee table using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

| EMPNO | ENAME | JOB | MGR | HIREDATE | SAL | COMM | DEPTNO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7698 | BLAKE | MANAGER | 7839 | 05/01/1981 | 2850 | - | 30 |
| 7839 | KING | PRESIDENT | - | 11/17/1981 | 5000 | - | 10 |
| 7782 | CLARK | MANAGER | 7839 | 06/09/1981 | 2450 | - | 10 |

What is a query that will return span of control, or the number of people reporting to each manager, given that the same 4-digit numbers appear in both the EMPNO, as well as the MGR columns?

If possible, I'd like to know how to get the result using both a subquery and/or a self join.

I used the following query:

```
SELECT e.ename, m.ename
from emp e, emp m
WHERE e.empno = m.mgr
```

It results in a table that lists the names of each employee that correspond to each manager.  Now, I just need to count the results and return a single number of employees grouped by each manager.  I've tired to nest the above query in a general query using the COUNT function, but can't get it to work.  A sample output of what I'd like to see is as follows:

| (manager)ENAME | (direct reports)COUNT_OF_ENAME |
| --- | --- |
| BLAKE | n |
| KING | n |
| CLARK | n |

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also specify the expected result - a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I've added rows and specified an expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will give you the manager id and a count of how many report to them

```
  SELECT MGR as MID, COUNT(*) AS REPORT_COUNT
  FROM emp
  GROUP BY MGR
```

Now we need to get the manager name with a join

```
  SELECT E.ENAME, REPORT_COUNT
  FROM (
    SELECT MGR as MID, COUNT(*) AS REPORT_COUNT
    FROM emp
    GROUP BY MGR 
  ) X
  JOIN emp E ON E.empno = x.MID
```